# BGW Multiplication with byzantine adversaries

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation, threshold-cryptography, matrix-multiplication

I have recently read about the BGW Multi-party Computation protocol, more specifically the multiplication gate by *Gennaro et al* ([PDF here](https://mit6875.github.io/PAPERS/GennaroRabinRabin.pdf)), however, some concepts raised questions.

**Context:** From what I understood, to multiply two secrets $a$ and $b$ each party $P_{i}$ is required to own two shares $f_{a}(i)$ and $f_{b}(i)$ previously shared from $f_{a}(x)$ and $f_{b}(x)$, both random polynomials of degree $t$ which define $f_{a}(0) = a$ and $f_{b}(0) = b$ respectively. Then, each party $P_{i}$ computes the product $f_{a}(i)f_{b}(i)$ and sends share $h_{i}(j)$ to party $P_{j}$ for $1 <= j <= 2t+1$, where $h_{i}(j)$ comes from a new random degree-$t$ polynomial $h_{i}(x)$ generated by $P_{i}$ where $h_{i}(0) = f_{a}(i)f_{b}(i)$. From this, each party will obtain the following configuration:

$
P_{1}: h_{1}(1), h_{2}(1), \ldots, h_{2t+1}(1) \\
P_{2}: h_{1}(2), h_{2}(2), \ldots, h_{2t+1}(2) \\
\vdots \\
P_{2t+1}: h_{1}(2t+1), h_{2}(2t+1), \ldots, h_{2t+1}(2t+1) \\
$

Finally, each party $P_{j}$ computes the linear equation:

$$
H(j)=\sum_{i=1}^{2t+1} \lambda_{i}h_{i}(j)
$$

, which retrieves an evaluation of a polynomial $H(x)$ of degree $t$ which satisfies $H(0)=\sum_{i=1}^{2t+1} \lambda_{i}h_{i}(0) = f_{a}(0)f_{b}(0) = ab$. Note that $\lambda_{i}$ are Lagrange coefficients which may be obtained via the first row of the inverse of the following $(2t+1)\times(2t+1)$ Vandermonde matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\
1 & 2 & \ldots & 2^{2t} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & 2t + 1 & \ldots & (2t + 1)^{2t} \\
\end{bmatrix}

Now, assume a simple scenario with byzantine adversaries (which may deviate from the protocol by crashing, sending invalid shares, etc.) that defines $t = 1$ and $n = 3t+1 = 4$. In theory, the protocol is secure in such a scenario as previous studies state that BGW provides security against $t < n/3$ malicious parties. With this, I have the following questions:

**Q1:** In section 4.2.2, the paper states that "each player $P_{i}$ shares $c_{i} = \lambda_{i}f_{a}(i)f_{b}(i)$ via our DL-VSS protocol, where $\lambda_{i}$ is the coefficient defined in Section 3.1". However, in this scenario, there exist $3t+1$ parties, and if the Vandermonde matrix is of $(2t+1)\times(2t+1)$ nature, then there will only be $2t+1 = 3$ coefficients which are not enough for the $3t+1 = 4$ parties.

**Q1.1:** One could change the Vandermonde matrix to be of nature $(3t+1)\times(2t+1)$. By generating the inverse it will create a matrix of nature $(2t+1)\times(3t+1)$ making the first row contain $3t+1$ coefficients, as desired. However, the first problem that arises is that because it ceases to be a square matrix, then it may not be invertible, and thus the coefficients cannot be obtained. The second problem is that by increasing the number of coefficients to $3t+1$, the number of required sub-shares is also proportionally increased to $3t+1$ for the previously defined formula to work correctly and so the initial $2t+1$ required sub-shares assumption is broken.

**Q2:** Another issue is that this scenario should tolerate $t = 1$ malicious adversaries, however, a possibility could be the party $P_{3}$ refusing to send their sub-shares of the multiplication to the other parties. But this cannot occur because the algorithm requires specifically the shares from the server $P_{1}$, $P_{2}$ and $P_{3}$ to correlate with the generated coefficients $\lambda_{1}$, $\lambda_{2}$ and $\lambda_{3}$. So, the only party that could in theory fail is party $P_{4}$, but if that is the case, then there is only a $25\%$ chance that the protocol works...

I would much appreciate any help in resolving such questions and sorry for the extensive thread!